# 2 tasks inside a msbuild loop

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
       <Projects Include="projectpath1"/>
       <Projects Include="projectpath2"/>
       ...
<ItemGroup/>

// foreach project {
<GetCss Project=%Project.Identity CssOutputs=@CssFiles/>
<MergeCss CssInputs=@CssFiles CssOutputFile="test.css"/>
 // } execute GetCss then MergeCss foreach project
```

GetCss and MergeCss are custom inline tasks.

I don't want:

```
// foreach project {
    <GetCss Project=%Project.Identity CssOutputs=@CssFiles/>
// }
// foreach project {
    <MergeCss CssInputs=@CssFiles CssOutputFile="test.css"/>
  // }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like you'd want to perform [target batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473(v=vs.100).aspx) so that you could call both of the inline tasks for each of your `Projects` items. Here's an example of a batched target named `GetAndMergeCss`, with the assumption that your `GetCss` inline task takes a string for an input and the `CssFiles` listed for `CssOuputs` are MSBuild items to be consumed by your `MergeCss` inline task:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Projects Include="projectpath1"/>
  <Projects Include="projectpath2"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="GetAndMergeCss" Outputs="%(Projects.Identity)">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ThisProjectIdentity>%(Projects.Identity)</ThisProjectIdentity>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="Preparing to get and merge css for project:  $(ThisProjectIdentity)" />

  <GetCss Project="$(ThisProjectIdentity)" CssOutputs="@(CssFiles)"/>
  <!--Or this works too...<GetCss Project="%(Projects.Identity)" CssOutputs="@(CssFiles)"/>-->

  <MergeCss CssInputs="@(CssFiles)" CssOutputFile="test.css"/>

</Target>
```